# Mongoose User model for handling local and social auth providers

Tags: facebook, express, mongoose, oauth, passport.js

So I am working on an Express (with Mongoose and Passport) app and I want to include facebook as an authentication method. I have already done it and it works but I don't think I have a proper User model to handle the authentication process for multiple social providers. I want to merge the different social accounts. Here is my current user model which works for facebook auth:

```js
let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    name: { type: String },
    password: { type: String },
    facebookId: String,
    facebookToken: String
}, { timestamps: true });
```

I think of the following two approaches but I am not sure if they are viable and which will be the most flexible and independent from the social provider.
I am thinking of having local and social arrays like this:

```js
let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local: {
        email: { type: String, unique: true },
        name: { type: String },
        password: { type: String },
    },
    facebook: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        email: String,
        name: String
    },
    google: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        email: String,
    }
}, { timestamps: true });
```

The third approach is just overwriting the social provider id (I am not sure if this is okay).

```js
let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        email: { type: String, unique: true },
        name: { type: String },
        id: String,
        token: String,
    }, { timestamps: true });
```

Comment: I am using second approach to handle local and social login. But when i try to login in with social profile i am getting error from mongo that the required fields of local must be filled. I marked some local profile data required. Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So I found a working solution for myself which might help other people with the same problem. In my User model I have my usual fields and for each social provider I have a separate array like so (users/User.js):

```js
let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    name: { type: String },
    password: { type: String },
    roles: [String],
    confirmation_code: String,
    confirmed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    facebook: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        email: String,
        name: String
    },
    google: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        email: String,
        name: String
    }
}, { timestamps: true });
```

When authenticating with a social provider I make an extra check if a user with the same email already exists. If it doesn't, I create a new user. If it does I just add the social provider data (id, token, etc.) to the already existing users array like so (config/passport.js):

```js
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: oauth.facebook.clientID,
    clientSecret: oauth.facebook.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: oauth.facebook.callbackURL,
    profileFields: ['id', 'emails', 'name']
},
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function () {
            User.findOne({
                $or: [
                    { 'facebook.id': profile.id },
                    { 'email': profile.emails[0].value }
                ]
            }, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }

                if (user) {
                    if (user.facebook.id == undefined) {
                        user.facebook.id = profile.id;
                        user.facebook.token = accessToken;
                        user.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value;
                        user.facebook.name = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
                        user.save();
                    }

                    return done(null, user);

                } else {
                    let newUser = new User();
                    newUser.facebook.id = profile.id;
                    newUser.facebook.token = accessToken;
                    newUser.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value;
                    newUser.facebook.name = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
                    newUser.name = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
                    newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value;

                    newUser.save(err => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            throw err;
                        }

                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
));
```

With this approach you can connect one profile with multiple social providers. However there is one downside. If the user registers a new profile for the first time through a social provider, he won't have a password because social providers don't give back password data (duh). He just needs to change (set) his password through his profile afterwards.